# Minimum of $K(x,y) = 15x + 19y$ if $x^2+7xy+2y^2=3200$ and $x,y\geq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm teaching calculus to someone and there is one problem I wasn't able to solve:

Determine the minimum of the function $K(x,y) = 15x+19y$ given that $x^2+7xy+2y^2=3200$ and $x,y\geq 0$

Usually, I'd rewrite the condition until it's of the form x = ... or y = ..., then substitute it into the function K, get a function in one variable and calculate its local extremum(s) by differentiating it and calculating the value for which it is zero. But I don't think it's possible to rewrite the condition in that manner, so any advice on how I would solve this would be appreciated!

The solution is supposed to be x = 18.74, y = 17.20 and I verified that it satisfies the condition.

Comment: *Hint*: look up Lagrange Multipliers.

Comment: The most obvious approach is to use Lagrangian multipliers. The geometric meaning is that the problem amounts to looking for $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $K(x,y)=K(x_0,y_0)$ defines a tangent line of the conic section $x^2+7xy+2y^2=3200$. But I think you may have omitted something: Did they require $x,y$ to both be positive? If not, then one can make $K(x,y)$ arbitrarily small.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, you're right, x and y are greater than or equal to 0. And as for macton: Thanks! I've used Lagrange Multipliers before, but didn't think of using them for this exercise. I think I'll be able to solve this then!

Comment: Okay, then you'll want to update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I updated the question and was able to solve it!

Comment: Good! I encourage you to post your worked solution as an answer to your own question: That'll both build your rep here and let us give feedback on your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding Lagrange function is $L(x,y) = 15x+19y - \lambda \cdot (x^2+7xy+2y^2-3200)$

In order to find a local extremum, we look for values where the partial derivatives are equal to 0, so we get the equations
$15-2x-7y=0$ and $19-7x-4y=0$.
This set of equations has the solutions $x = \frac{73}{41\lambda}$ and $y = \frac{67}{41\lambda}$. Putting these values for x and y into the condition $x^2 + 7xy + 2y^2=3200$ and solving the equation for $\lambda$, we get $\lambda = \frac{\sqrt{1517}}{410}$.

As a result, $x = \frac{73}{41\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1517}}{410}} \approx 18.74$ and $x = \frac{67}{41\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1517}}{410}} \approx 17.2$

With these values, we get that $K(18.74,17.2) = 607.9$.

Now we look at the edge cases:

If $x = 0$, then $3200 = 2y^2 \Rightarrow y = 40 \Rightarrow K(0,40)=760$

If $y = 0$, then $3200 = x^2 \Rightarrow x = \sqrt{3200} \Rightarrow K(\sqrt{3200},0)\approx 848.53 $

In both cases, we ignored the negative solutions for x and y because they are both non-negative.

Since the values of $K$ at the edges are bigger than $K(18.74,17.2)=607.9$, the local minimum (18.74, 17.2) is the global minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Let $p=15x+19y\implies y=?$

Replace this value of $y$ in $$x^2+7xy+2y^2-3200=0$$ to form a quadratic equation in $x$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$